# "StaleElementReferenceException: Element not found in the cache - perhaps the page has changed since it was looked up

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I want to find out the broken links on page.

But I am getting an error  on second iteration When i try to click on second link (to check broken links on page )

```
StaleElementReferenceException: Element not found in the cache - perhaps the page has changed since it was looked up Command duration or timeout: 47 milliseconds"
```

here is my code :

```
    WebElement element =driver.findElement(By.tagName("a"));
    List<WebElement> links = driver.findElements(By.tagName("a"));
   System.out.println(links.size());

   for (int index=0; index<links.size(); index++ ) { 
       links.get(index).click();
       driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
       driver.getTitle();
       driver.navigate().back(); 

       }
```

Can anyone please let me know I have made a mistake ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Selenium Webdriver with Java: Element not found in the cache - perhaps the page has changed since it was looked up](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17972359/selenium-webdriver-with-java-element-not-found-in-the-cache-perhaps-the-page)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can't store element on the page, browse, and then come back to use them. Each time you arrive on a new page, you need to select them again (kind of a refresh).

Try something like this

```
   for (int index=0; index<links.size(); index++ ) {
      links = driver.findElements(By.tagName("a")); 
      links.get(index).click();
      driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
      driver.getTitle();
      driver.navigate().back(); 
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

If the page reloads links (List of webelements) will lost the hold to click on next elements.

You can do something like below to click on each link in loop.

```
WebElement element =driver.findElement(By.tagName("a"));
List<WebElement> links = driver.findElements(By.tagName("a"));
System.out.println(links.size());

for (int index=0; index<links.size(); index++ ) { 
       driver.findElements(By.tagName("a")).get(i).click(); //this is what I've change
       driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
       driver.getTitle();
       driver.navigate().back(); 

 }
```