# iterate over result pages using selenium and python: StaleElementReferenceException

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I think for people who understood the selenium tool will now laugh but maybe you can share you're knowledge because really want to laugh now, too.

My code is this:

```
def getZooverLinks(country):

    global countries
    countries = country

    zooverWeb = "http://www.zoover.nl/"
    url = zooverWeb + country

    driver = webdriver.Firefox()
    driver.get(url)

    button = driver.find_element_by_class_name('next')

    links = []

    for page in xrange(1,4):
        WebDriverWait(driver, 60).until(lambda driver :driver.find_element_by_class_name('next'))
        divList = driver.find_elements_by_class_name('blue2')
        for div in divList:
            hrefTag = div.find_element_by_css_selector('a').get_attribute('href')
            print(hrefTag)
            newLink = zooverWeb + hrefTag
            links.append(newLink)

            button.click()
            driver.implicitly_wait(10)

        time.sleep(60)
     return links
```

So I want to iterate over all result pages and always get the links from the divs having the class="blue2" and then follow the "next"-link to get to the next result page.
But always I get a StaleElementReferenceException saying:
"Message: Element not found in the cache - perhaps the page has changed since it was looked up"

But the layout of pages is always the same. So what is the problem here? Is the url after the click not handed over to the driver since the page changes too? How can I do that?

Comment: Similar issue - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17972359/selenium-webdriver-with-java-element-not-found-in-the-cache-perhaps-the-page

Comment: Thanks for the great tip. I included the button = ... in the for-loop and it worked perfectly!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a little bit tricky to follow the pagination on this particular site.

Here is the set of things that helped me to overcome the issue with `StaleElementReferenceException`:

- find elements inside the loop since the page changes
- use [Explicit Waits](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/en/latest/waits.html#explicit-waits) to wait for the specific page numbers to become active

Working code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

country = "albanie"
zooverWeb = "http://www.zoover.nl/"

url = zooverWeb + country

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get(url)
driver.implicitly_wait(10)

links = []
for page in xrange(1, 4):
    # tricky part - waiting for the page number on the top to appear
    if page > 1:
        WebDriverWait(driver, 60).until(EC.text_to_be_present_in_element((By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'div.entityPagingTop strong'), str(page)))
    else:
        WebDriverWait(driver, 60).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME, 'next')))

    divList = driver.find_elements_by_class_name('blue2')
    for div in divList:
        hrefTag = div.find_element_by_css_selector('a').get_attribute('href')
        newLink = zooverWeb + hrefTag
        links.append(newLink)

    driver.find_element_by_class_name("next").click()

print links
```

Comment: That works as well pretty well. Can you tell me what you do in the if-statement?

Comment: @StefanieBeutke yeah, basically we are waiting for the current page number to appear as "strong" in the pagination block - this is a good indication that the page changed. And we don't need to check the page number if this is the first page - in this case we simply wait for "next" button to appear. Hope that makes sense.

Comment: That is pretty cool. I didn't know about strong thing. Thank you a lot